# Safari on macOS does not show the tabs open in the iPad's Safari

Tags: macos, ipad, icloud, safari, ipados

When I check the tabs open in the iPad's Safari from the Safari app in macOS they are not at sync.

In macOS I see a set of open tabs in the iPad which are not. I close the from macOS but as soon as I start Safari on the iPad they pop up again.

Works OK with the iPhone.

Any guess on why it happens and how can it be solved?

All devices are updated.

Comment: Is Handoff enabled on the iPad?

Comment: On the iPad, is Settings > iCloud > Safari toggled "on" ?

Comment: Try logging out of iCloud on your iPad and logging in again.

Comment: Handoff is enabled and Safari toggle on. I tried to toggling it off and logging out and in again of iCloud but still no results. By the way, I also see the same "stuck" tabs in the iPhone.

Comment: I‘ve experienced sync problems of Safari tabs between iPhone and iPad for a long time and reported this multiple times to Apple. Sometimes it works for a while, then syncing no longer works. I also experienced zombie tabs that re-appeared again and again. iCloud syncing of Safari tabs seems to be just very unreliable and Apple seems to have other priorities…